# Outlook Addin How to Make Custom Tab Show Only in New Message Compose Window

Tags: outlook, tabs, outlook-addin, add-in, ribbon

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this that I am overlooking. But, how do you make a custom tab in the Ribbon.xml show up only in the new message compose window? I want to have my own tab so that the ribbon for my groups and buttons will be clean.

I am currently doing a workaround to invalidate the tab control when a new mail item event happens, but there must be a simpler way to do this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

It's Outlook 2016 desktop in Windows 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ribbon XML must specify only `Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/customizing-a-ribbon-for-outlook?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitry! This totally simplified what I was doing in the code. I had both the Mail.Compose and Outlook.Explorer ribbonIDs in my GetCustomUI function. Your help is very much appreaciated.